# 'DateTimeImmutable' class not found in php

Tags: php

I'm running a php version 8.1.23 with yii2 project and i'm trying to use DateTimeImmutable for the first time and i got this error "Class "DateTimeImmutable" not found", below is the line of code that produces the error

```
$time   = new DateTimeImmutable();
```

after making some searching online i realized it has to do with PHP version but the error should occur in lower php version. >= version 5.4 should support it, but i don't know why it's not working here. I'm not sure if this is php problem or yii2 problem . any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any different result with `new \DateTimeImmutable();`?

Comment: To rule out that yii2 is related: when running code **without** that framework involved, does it throw the same error?

Comment: @Nico Haase Thanks for your response, I managed to fix the error what i needed to do is to add use DateYimeImmutable; to the top of my file then now use it